# Install Kubeflow on specific node of Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubeflow

I want to deploy kubeflow on a specific node of an existing Kubernetes cluster.

Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, you need to select the node based on its labels

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/#equality-based-requirement

Comment: I'm just starting to learn Kubernetes & Kubeflow and I don't see how to apply that to Kubeflow installation. Kubeflow "kfctl build" command allows to generate a set of "kustomization.yaml" files, which contains (all of them) "kind: Kustomization" lines. This configuration is then deployed into my cluster by running "kfctl apply". But there is no "kind: Pod" or "spec" entries. So, I don't know where to add the nodeSelector entry. I'm trying to follow this guide: https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/started/k8s/kfctl-k8s-istio/, should I modify kfctl_k8s_istio.v1.1.0.yaml? How? Thanks.